# How can I pass False value to a boolean cflag in cpp?

Tags: c++, cflags

I've declared a boolean flag

```
DEFINE_bool(coolflag, true, "My cool flag.");
```

and then want to run my binary with `coolflag=false`:

```
... --coolflag false
```

but the value of the flag is still true:

```
cout << FLAGS_coolflag << endl; // outputs 1
```

I tried `false`, `False`, `0`, but the value is still 1 (true).

How can I set `coolflag=false`?

Comment: what is DEFINE_bool ? could you provide minimal, complete example please ?

Comment: What do you mean "run your binary"? Shouldn't cflags be *compiler* flags?

Comment: For command-line arguments, the common practice for double-dash arguments it to use a `=` for the value, as in `--coolflag=false`. If this is true for whatever API you're using I don't know. Perhaps it should be `--no-coolflag` or something else entirely. Have you tried reading the documentation about `DEFINE_bool` and what it expects?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right! It works when I use `--coolflag=false`.